# How to create tooltip in spreadsheet using Java-Jsp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, css

I really need a help/hints/explanation of how to implement a tooltip/comment in spreadsheet just like the one in google-spreadsheeting (right-click and insert comment).

Example : 
![tooltip] https://sites.google.com/a/wongsk.twbbs.org/wongsk/image2/popupinexcel.jpg

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is create the tooltip itself, take a look on the [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) jQuery plugin.